# DTaskManager Runtime '5' error?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, task-manager, visual-basic, runtime-error

I really enjoy using DTaskManager as an alternative to Windows TaskManager, but recently I've been getting Runtime Error '5' messages. It looks like DTaskManager was programmed in Visual Basic 6, but it is quite powerful. I'm running Windows 7 Enterprise x64 so I suspect that the error might be coming from a Visual Basic runtime problem. I'm not sure which registry keys to edit to fix the Runtime Error '5' message.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old but it's one of the first results that pop up when you search this error and I would like to help out others who have this problem.

The problem may be caused by an application that manipulates how windows are displayed (like AWM (Actual Window Manager)). I also use DTaskManager and it was working right up until I installed AWM. From then on, it gave me the rune-time error '5' messages whenever I ran it.

Uninstalling AWM fixed the problem.
The version of AWM I had was 6.5.1

OS: Windows 7 64bit Ult

Comment: I don't believe that I installed this software, but it's good to know about this solution for those who are using AWM.